# Записать в бинарный файл

Tags: java, файлы

Возможно ли в java строку из нулей и единиц записать в двоичный файл? Но чтобы потом можно было прочитать этот двоичный файл, и его содержимое должно быть равно начальной строке из нулей и единиц. То есть, например, есть строка `String OPER = "00100011101";`, я её записываю в бинарный файл, потом его читаю, и в командной строке должно быть написано это: `00100011101`.

Comment: Да, возможно. У вас в чем конкретно проблема?

Comment: @compl Это не проблема, это постановка задачи. Вы хотите, чтобы мы решали задачу за вас? Или у вас есть более конкретный вопрос?

Comment: @compl: Тогда вопрос: _что_ должно содержаться в файле? Какие байты? Например, для вашего случая исходной строки `"00100011101"`.

Расширение и содержимое, как вы понимаете, друг на друга не влияют.

Comment: @compl: Всякий файл — не более чем набор байт. Любой формат — текст, картинка, аудио — есть «надстройка» над потоком байт. Например, текст кодируется байтами, включая концы строк. С этой точки зрения любой файл — двоичный. Как именно можно закодировать информацию в нём? Да как угодно!

Можно, например, записывать каждый символ в Unicode-последовательность байт. Можно закодировать каждый символ как байт с ASCII-кодом цифр 0 или 1. Можно записывать 0-байт для символа "0" и 1-байт для символа "1". Можно упаковать ваши цифры в байт по 8 штук (одна на бит) и записать эти биты. Можно как угодно.

Comment: @compl: Так что это **вам** надо решить (ну или уточнить у преподавателя, если это учебное задание), какими байтами вы будете кодировать вашу строку (с оглядкой на то, что придётся и раскодировать потом), превратить строку в этот набор байт, и записать эти байты в файл. Повторюсь: файл — это и есть набор байт на диске.

«Бинарный» означает «никакого предписанного формата нет», так что как отображать строку на байты (то есть по сути формат) вам придётся назначить самостоятельно.

Comment: @compl: А, ну да. Тогда так:

    byte[] bytes = new byte[OPER.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < OPER.length(); i++)
        bytes[i] = (OPER.charAt(i) == '0') ? 0 : 1;

Ну и записываете массив байтов в файл.

(У меня заканчивается лимит комментариев, я удаляю старые.)

Comment: @compl (byte)0, (byte)1 или 0b0 и 0b1.

Comment: @compl: У вас `OPER.charAt(i)`, а надо же `OPER.charAt(i) == '0'`.

Comment: @VladD, да уж. Но всё равно там еще к (byte) надо было привести: bytes[i] = (byte) ((OPER.charAt(i) == '0') ? 0 : 1);

Comment: @compl: Нет, блокнот не поймёт исходный текст. Для блокнота (текстовый формат) `'0'` должен быть байтом с кодом 49, а вы пишете 0.

Comment: @VladD, это то, что нужно. Если я запишу этот массив байтов в файл, потом можно будет этот массив прочитать из файла и записать в новую строку?

Comment: @compl: Разумеется. Вы читаете массив байт, превращаете его в массив _символов_ (0 -> `'0'`, 1 -> `'1'`), и конструируете из массива символов строку.

Comment: @VladD, отлично. Записал я таким образом:

`try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("someFile.dat"))) {
            fos.write(bytes);
            fos.close();
        }`

Потом открыл этот файл через VS, и там моя строка, только идет по 2 символа, т.е. "00 00 01" и т.д. Почему по 2 символа?

Comment: @compl: 

> открыл этот файл через VS

А откуда VS знает ваш формат? Вы ж его только что сами выдумали.

Открывайте HEX editor'ом.

Comment: @VladD, я не знаю, но там в точности моя строка, только перед каждым символом 0.

Comment: @compl: Может быть, VS показывает по две hex-цифры на байт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
byte[] bytes = "asdasd".getBytes();
String str = new String(bytes);
```

А куда записывать и откуда считывать вы, наверное, сами разберетесь.

Comment: Не то, что нужно.